# NSAttributedString: underline is not applied

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, underline

I'm trying to add underline style for `UITextView` and it's not applied. If i use "shadow" (uncomment shadow styling and comment underline styling) i can see it, but no underline is applied for some reason. I use "Courier New" font.

```
- (void) addDiagHighlighting: (NSMutableAttributedString*)attrString start:(int)start end:(int)end severity:(int)severity {
    // ignore diags that are out of bounds
    if (start > attrString.length || end > attrString.length)
        return;

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, end - start);
    UIColor *diagColor = [self getSeverityColor: severity];

    // shadow
//    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
//    [shadow setShadowColor: diagColor];
//    [shadow setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake (1.0, 1.0)];
//    [shadow setShadowBlurRadius: 1.0];
//    [attrString addAttribute:NSShadowAttributeName
//                       value:shadow
//                       range:range];

    // underline
    [attrString addAttributes:@{
                                NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : diagColor, // color
                                NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlinePatternSolid) // style
                                }
                       range:range];
}
```

i can change adding attributes to adding both shadow and underling and i can see shadow but still no underline:

```
// shadow + underline
[attrString addAttributes:@{
                            NSShadowAttributeName : shadow, // shadow
                            NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : diagColor, // color
                            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlinePatternSolid) // style
                            }
                   range:range];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to OR a `NSUnderlinePattern` with an `NSUnderlineStyle` to get it working ([see Apple documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nsunderlinestyle))

Try this:

```
[attrString addAttributes:@{
                        NSShadowAttributeName : shadow, // shadow
                        NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : diagColor, // color
                        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternSolid) // style
                        }
               range:range];
```

Or with dots...

```
[attrString addAttributes:@{
                        NSShadowAttributeName : shadow, // shadow
                        NSUnderlineColorAttributeName : diagColor, // color
                        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternDot) // style
                        }
               range:range];
```

Answer (score 6):

The Apple Developer Documentation states about [`NSUnderlineStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsunderlinestyle):

> The style, pattern, and optionally by-word mask are OR'd together to produce the value for `underlineStyle` and `strikethroughStyle`.

Therefore, with Swift 5 and iOS 12.3, you can use the [*bitwise OR operator*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID28) (`|`) to set a style and a pattern together for `NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle` attribute.

---

The following Playground sample code shows how to set both  `NSUnderlineStyle.thick` and `NSUnderlineStyle.patternDot` attributes for a `NSAttributedString` instance:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle : (NSUnderlineStyle.thick.rawValue | NSUnderlineStyle.patternDot.rawValue)]
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Some text", attributes: attributes)

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
label.backgroundColor = .white
label.attributedText = attributedString

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = label
```